# What is the default current working directoy of a service in Windows?

Tags: windows-services, directory

I'm adapting a program to run as a service, and the first thing it does is open a local configuration file, but it doesn't exist because I don't know what is the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

The current working directory is the location of the executable of the service, unless modified using the win32 API call `SetCurrentDirectory`

Answer (score 1):

Calling `GetCurrentDirectory` at the service entry point returns "C:\WINDOWS\system32". After setting it to the executable's directory with `SetCurrentDirectory` everything worked as expected.

Comment: But, why the system is setting current directoy to windows\system32 initially .. ??